# Quick way to find a number that, when multiplied by a given number, equals the outcome of a given modulo operation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm interested in solving the following equation:

$$9x\equiv 58 \pmod{101}$$

Meaning taking $\pmod{101}$ of $9 \times$ some number $x$ will equal $58$.  I know how to solve this using a table—in class, we were told we should start by plugging in values for x, starting with 0, like so:

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  x & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
  \hline
  9x-58 \pmod{101} & -58 & -49 & -40
 \end{array}
and then take $\pmod{101}$ of each $f(x)$ until a zero was obtained.  However, this method seems somewhat impractical for large numbers.  For instance, I looked online and found the answer to my question is $x=85$.  Is there some way to find the answer quicker? I know how to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm; not sure if it would aid in  this instance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the extended Euclidean algorithm is the best tool here. Try finding integers $x$ and $y$ for which

$$9x + 101 y = 58$$

This is possible since $9$ and $101$ have greatest common divisor $1$, so a solution to $9a + 101b = 1$ can be found. Then $x$ will be the desired solution.

Comment: $x$ won't be the inverse of $9$, it will be $58 \cdot 9^{-1}$.  Just a typo, it seems.

Comment: @AWalker Yes, I was typing too fast. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give me some initial first steps to try to solve that? I know how to solve for 9x + 101y = 1 by working in reverse after finding the GCD (i.e., 1 = 9 - 2*4 and then substituting in what 2 equals next), but how would I go about solving it for 58? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use extended Euclidean algorithm to find

$$9a + 101b = GCD(9, 101) = 1$$

If you multiply both sides with 58, you get

$$ 9(58a) + 101(58b) = 58$$

And so $58a$ would be the $x$ you wish to find. To get all general solutions, find the $LCM(9,101)$:
$$9\cdot101 = 101\cdot9 = LCM(9,101)\\
9\cdot101-101\cdot9 = 0$$

And so generally $x= 58a + 101n$ is also a solution.

Notice, this method does not require $p$ to have an inverse in general to solve $px\equiv q\pmod{n}$. For example, you can as well solve $9x\equiv60\pmod{102}$.

Comment: Hi, would you mind giving me some initial first steps to go about this?

Comment: So if you know how to use extended Euclidean algorithm, you should find $-11\cdot9+1\cdot102 = 3=GCD(9,102)$, and when you multiply both sides by $\frac{60}{GCD(9,102)}$, you get $\color{red}{-220\cdot9+20\cdot102=60}$. So we know $x=-220$ is one of the solutions. To find more solutions, check that $34\cdot9 = 3\cdot102 = 306 = LCM(9,102)$, and so $\color{green}{34\cdot9-3\cdot102=0}$. Add this to the previous red equation any integer times to get $(34n-220)9+(20-3n)102=60$. This gives general solution $x\equiv-220\pmod{34}$. Notice this works even there is no $9^{-1}$ in mod $102$.

Comment: For your original case, you should find $45\cdot9-4\cdot101=1$. Multiply both sides by $58$ to get $\color{red}{2610\cdot9-232\cdot101=58}$. Therefore $2610$ is one of the solutions. Also check that $101\cdot9=9\cdot101=LCM(9,101)$, so $\color{green}{101\cdot9-9\cdot101=0}$. Add any integer times of this to the red equation, we get $(2610+101n)9 - (232+9n)101=58$. This gives general solution $x\equiv2610\pmod{101}$. In this case, this method is similar to multiplying $9^{-1}$ to both sides of $9x\equiv58\pmod{101}$.

Comment: Great—really appreciate it!